# Decrypting yii2 password

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, password-encryption

I need to display the password of a user in his account details page in my website which has been created using yii2 framework.
Is there any way to show the actual password from the password hash that is stored in DB.

Comment: **You should never *show* the password back to the user**. The reason for this is that if you do, you have **gigantic** security hole in your system. Don't store passwords, only store their hashes. If you already do this, then you **cannot** show the user his or her password.

Answer (score 0):

You have to encrypt the password and store it in the db.
You can use [Yii 2 Encrypter](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-encrypter/) extensions to encrypt the password.
For the work flow of encrypting and password validation you can follow Advanced template user model work flow. Only difference is we have to encrypt the password and in getPassword() function, we need to decrypt the password.

**But normally people would usually hash the password and store it in the DB. It should be always one way to avoid security issues.**

Comment: Never encrypt passwords.